# How to navigate in server using angular

Tags: angular, nginx, devops, devops-services

I make a angular application My angular application is  running  on nginx server . When I type “http://**.8.100.248:30749”  it show nginx is running. (Showing default index.html). But my application is present in `html` folder  having folder name `test`.  So my application present in  “html —> test—> index.html”;  When I type “http://**.8.100.248:30749/text/index.html” it show my home page .Now I can navigate from one page to another page on button click example . **http://**.8.100.248:30749/test/page_1**.But when I reload this page `http://**.8.100.248:30749/test/page_1` nginx show me `404` page

So when I type http://**.8.100.248:30749/test/index.html. .my application run on browser.but when I route from one page to another and `reload` my page it gives me `404` example (`http://**.8.100.248:30749/test/page_1`) .

Nginx gives me 404 when I reload my angular routed page. So  I want to change the nginx config

```
     location / {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
           index  index.html index.htm;
   }
```

can you please suggest me the way . ? it is doing behaviour because there is no index.html file in this location (`http://**.8.100.248:30749/test/page_1`)

see update

```
location / {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
           index  index.html index.htm;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
```

New update

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because initially, you are able to navigate due to Angular routes, however, on page refresh, the request goes through Nginx again and Nginx is unable to find the route.

Add this to your Nginx config :

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

A sample Nginx server block that solves your issue is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
     }
}
```

UPDATE :

Since your index.html resides inside the test directory,
Use this

`try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html;`

Comment: see update after using your solution .Now it is show `500` error on reload . and it is also show `http://**.8.100.248:30749` 403 on default

Comment: move root and index configs outside the location block and try, see the sample server block.

Comment: same result .I restarted nginx it is show 500 error on reload . and it is also show http://**.8.100.248:30749 403 on default –

Comment: hi in your case it needs to be `try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html;`

updated the answer

Comment: sorry checking sorry  for late reply

Comment: @user944513 Accept the answer if it helped